# count multiple occurence of a list of items

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table like this

```
|id  |item_list                     | 
|----|------------------------------|
|1   |["cat","apple","dog"]         |
|2   |["mango","dog"]               |
|3   |["blabla","ant","snake","cat"]|
|4   |["tree","grass"]              |
```

So lets I want to count the number of items in the cell each from this list of items below

```
dog, cat, ant, snake
```

This is my desired result:

```
|   id   |          item_list           | count |
|--------|------------------------------|-------| 
|    1   |["cat","apple","dog"]         | 2     | 
|    2   |["mango","dog"]               | 1     |
|    3   |["blabla","ant","snake","cat"]| 3     |
|    4   |["tree","grass"]              | 0     |
```

Can I know how can I count the numbers of desired values in the list and ignore the rest to have same result as in the table above? I'm using Redshift

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some ancient roots, they are quite different

Comment: Hi sorry i dont quite get your question. Just to extend a little on your question, my datalake is on Redshift while when I perform my sql query to check on the Postgres version, it says my Postgres version is 8.0.2